# How Do I Deal With System Data Filling Up My Mac Drive?

Tags: installation, macos-monterey

I have a 256Gb Drive in a 512Mb Mac mini. Looking at the drive in System Information, it shows that I have something [image]

like 175Gb of System Data. I have no idea what this is, or where to go looking for it, but it's making use of the machine impossible.

How do I identify where and what this is, and how can I be rid of it? It makes no sense to me that Apple sells a machine that as a default leaves 75Gb of drive space for System,files, Apps and everything else, so I'm assuming this is an anomaly and something can be done.

My goal was to reinstall Monterey, but I can't as there isn't enough drive space to do so...This machine is used by Final Cut Pro and Xcode, so I'm sure that there's loads of potential there, but I've already gone in and cleared out most of the iOS Simulators, which seemed to be the bulk of the Xcode drive-hoggery. As well as deleting Xcode and Final Cut.

Also: I normally have iCloud backing things up, as well as Time Machine, and both have very up to date versions of the drive. So I'm not too worried about data loss, as well as having Git repos of the main code projects. So I think there's not much risk here. Is it a good idea to just reformat the drive and start again? That is something I'd like to avoid if there's no good argument for it. The other option I think I have is to get a larger external SSD and set that up as a startup drive. Is there a recommended path among these choices?

I turned off iCloud and stopped its back up because it was simply filling up the drive. I had about 45Gb free, by deleting things like the FCP files to install Montery from Recovery, but I stepped away and by then iCloud had gone back to filling the damned thing up.

Now the Documents, Desktop and Downloads, where I keep 95% of non-app stuff are completely empty, with the exception of a gig or so in Downloads.

Any help gratefully received.

EDIT: The primary culprit was ~/Library/Developer. I'm reinstalling Xcode, so I deleted all the Developer files, and this is what it looks like now: [image]

Comment: Check out [this article](https://www.macworld.com/article/676493/how-to-delete-system-storage-on-mac.html).

Comment: That article doesn't seem to deal with the question: what is "System Data", and how do I access it and get rid of it. My problem doesn't really fit into that category.

Comment: @DanDonaldson Yes it does. Scroll down to "What is in System in Mac storage (aka macOS)?"

Comment: Important Note: iCloud is not a backup solution, it is a sync solution. Also, if you use Optimise Storage & have a large amount of data offloaded because the drive is too full, then freeing space will simply cause some of that data to be re-downloaded. That's why you don't seem to be gaining. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5353/85275

Comment: I get the distinction, yes. The problem in fact was a combination of the re-filling the drive, and a huge amount of data in ~/Library/Developer that took up so much of the space that I couldn't clear enough to leave room.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I identify where and what this is, and how can I be rid of it?

Have you clicked the "`manage`" button and followed the [instructions](https://%5BHow%20To%20Clear%20System%20Storage%20On%20Mac%20%7C%20Macworld%5D(https://www.macworld.com/article/676493/how-to-delete-system-storage-on-mac.html))?

> **What is System Data Storage on a Mac?**
>
> System Data contains files that do not fall into categories such as
> Documents, Apps, iCloud Drive, Photos, Other Users, etc.. The primary
> files it includes are:
>
> - Log files and caches.
> - Temporary files.
> - VM files.
> - Fonts and plug-ins.
> - App support files.
> - Files and data used by the system.
> - Runtime system resources.
>
> The size of System Data varies depending on the state of your Mac.
> Since some of the files mentioned above are not necessary, you can
> delete them to lessen their impact on your storage.
>
> **How to Clear System Data Storage on Mac**
>
> Although, we don't have full control over the System Data storage,
> there are a few things we can do to reduce its size. Read on! Optimize
> Mac Storage
>
> macOS Sierra and later come with a feature to optimize Mac storage.
> Just click the Manage button above the storage bar.
>
> **Clear Caches on Mac**
>
> The system and applications you run on your Mac will create cache
> files in the Library Folder. To reclaim more space for your Mac, you
> can delete unneeded cache files manually.
>
> - Click the Go menu in Finder and select Go to Folder.
> - Paste the following file paths into the search box and click the Return key.
>
>   ~/Library/Caches/
>   /Library/Caches/
>   /System/Library/Caches/
> - Move unwanted files in these cache folders to the Trash.
> - Empty your Trash.

Source: [What Is System Data Storage on Mac and How to Clear It](https://www.drbuho.com/how-to/clear-system-storage-mac)

Comment: Yes, I had done those things, thanks for the aswer. I think maybe 25 Gb was in caches, but it still leaves me with this huge "System Data" section. That's the actual topic of my question. I've added another external drive, and I'll play around with that too. I think I can live with what I got...